# Indy, TidNotify and closing TidTCPServer

Tags: connection, indy

I have a TidTCPServer which use database manipulating inside onExcecute event (by using TidNotify). Everything works very good instead of possibility closing application. 
During closing application I do not know whether everything Notify instances finished their work or not and usually I get Runtime Error 216 (I think I close database before "notify" work end).
Is any way to check - are there waiting old Notify posts or not to be sure I can close application.
Other question is how to protect TidTCPServer from accepting new connection during closing server process.
I use code like below but I obtain the error still.

```
type
  TShutdownThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;


procedure TShutdownThread.Execute;
begin
  IdTCPServer.Active := false;
end;


//closing...
  if IdTCPServer.Active then
  begin
    with TShutdownThread.Create(false) do
      try
        WaitFor; // internally processes sync requests...
      finally
        Free;
      end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is any way to check - are there
 waiting old Notify posts or not to be sure I can close
 application.**

`TIdNotify` is asynchronous, it posts requests to the main thread message queue for later execution.  It is possible that pending requests are still in the queue after `TShutdownThread.WaitFor()` has exited.  You can call the RTL's `CheckSynchronize()` function to process any remaining requests, eg:

```
if IdTCPServer.Active then
begin
  with TShutdownThread.Create(false) do
  try
    WaitFor;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
  CheckSynchronize;
end;
```

**how to protect TidTCPServer from accepting new connection during closing server process.**

While `TIdTCPServer` is being deactivated, it closes its listening port(s) for you. However, there is a very small window of opportunity when new clients could be accepted before the server closes the port(s).  The server will close those connections as part of its shutdown, but if you do not want the `OnExecute` event to be called for those connections then you can set a flag somewhere in your code before deactivating the server, then check for that flag in the `OnConnect` event, and if it is set then disconnect the client immediately, eg:

```
var
  ShuttingDown: boolean = False;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  if ShuttingDown then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
    Exit;
  end;
  ...
end;

...

if IdTCPServer.Active then
begin
  ShuttingDown := True;
  try
    with TShutdownThread.Create(false) do
    try
      WaitFor;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
    CheckSynchronize;
  finally
    ShuttingDown := False;
  end;
end;
```